# Given a real analytic set, is it possible to find a real analytic function defined on an open neighborhood of it such that it's its zero set?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I have some basic question about analytic sets in real analytic manifolds which I couldn't find an answer to. Let $M$ be a real analytic manifold and $A \subset M$ be an analytic set. I know by the definition of an analytic set that for every $x \in A$ there is an open neighborhood $U \subset M$ of $x$ and a real analytic function $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$
A \cap U = \left\{ p \in U \mid f(p)=0 \right\}.
$$

So, locally the answer to my question is 'yes', and that's just the definition of an analytic set. But is it possible to find such 'global' $f$ defined on some open neighborhood of $A$ (but not necessarily on all of $M$)? If it's not always possible, is it possible under the further assumption that $A$ is a finite union of smooth (embedded) submanifolds of $M$, each of which is an analytic set?